# Android: How to perform a clean check for existence of a folder possibly created via getDir()?

Tags: android, file-io, android-file

I am looking for a "clean" way to check whether the folder potentially created via context.getDir() - exists.

I have some legacy code doing:

```
File folder = context.getDir("custom", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

This code creates a sub-folder named "app_custom" (app_ prefix is added by the system) in the folder used by the application.

I need to check whether the folder exists there.

getDir() itself is not useful for this purpose, since according to the documentation, it creates the folder when it doesn't exist.

I wonder what's the clean way to check whether the folder exists (no assumptions, no "side effects" like creating a folder that isn't there).

Thanks for any hint
Max

Comment: `folder.exists()`.

Comment: Or do you mean that you want to check if the folder exists before you call getDir()?

Comment: `in the "root" folder used by the application.`. There is no root folder. Please tell how you determine that folder.

Comment: Please tell the value of folder.getAbsolutePath(). Also tell the absolute path of your root folder.

Comment: Hi, indeed before calling getDir() since I want to avoid creation. On my  phone, the folder name is /data/user/0/com.mycompany.myapp.debug/app_custom. But I don't want to "hardcode" this path. The only assumption I make is that the folder was created via getDir("custom", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) API call.

Comment: Well then put in your post that you want to avoid creation. Looks essential info to me. Further you did not supply the requested root path.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I edited the title. As for the "root": I meant "/data/user/0/com.mycompany.myapp.debug", as opposed to "/data/user/0/com.mycompany.myapp.debug/files" which is returned by context.getFilesDir() - not the Android root.

Comment: So you want to know if `/data/user/0/com.mycompany.myapp.debug/app_custom` exists. And you know already `getFilesDir()` which gives you `/data/user/0/com.mycompany.myapp.debug/files`. And you have no idea how you can use that to construct the needed path? To do what you want to check?

Comment: `I edited the title. `. Yes. But the title does not make sense. And you forgot to mention avoiding creation in your post. So unclear all.